# How do I change the text of a ComboBox item?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox filed with the name of dataGridView columns, can I change the text of displayed items in the comboBox  to any text I want ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[i].ValueType == typeof(string) && 
        i != 6 && 
        i != 7 && 
        i != 8 && 
        i != 9)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name);
}
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Absolutely, but can you please post some code?

Comment: Yes it is possible for you to do that.

Comment: Is this WPF or Forms?  Can you tag your question as well?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I hope this helps you:

```
combobox.Items[combobox.FindStringExact("string value")] = "new string value";
```

The `FindStringExact` method returns the index of an specific item text, so this can be a better way to change the text of a `Combobox` item.

Note: This works fine on C#.

Comment: Never knew I could edit item's text like this. `combobox.Items[int index]= "new text";`

Answer (score 5):

If the value you want to use is not suitable as the text in a combobox, I usually do something like this:

```
public class ComboBoxItem<T> {
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxItem(string friendlyName, T value) {
        FriendlyName = friendlyName;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return FriendlyName;
    }
};

// ...
List<ComboBoxItem<int>> comboBoxItems = new List<ComboBoxItem<int>>();                      
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    comboBoxItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem<int>("Item " + i.ToString(), i));
}

_comboBox.DisplayMember = "FriendlyName";
_comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
_comboBox.DataSource = comboBoxItems;


_comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    Console.WriteLine("Selected Text:" + _comboBox.SelectedText);
    Console.WriteLine("Selected Value:" + _comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ListItem item = comboBox1.Items.FindByText("<Text>");
if (item != null)
{
   item.Text = "<New Text>";
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to retain the value of the column name, but display something more intuitive or just formatted better.

Comment: If that's the case, couldn't he set the item value to the actual column name, and change the text to something more readable/intuitive?

Comment: I assume he's using Winforms; don't think you can do that unless he sets the DataSource and populates DisplayMember and ValueMember or uses a custom class that separates text and value.

Answer (score 0):

May be instead of changing the text it would be simple to remove the item from a particular index and insert new item at same index with new text

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change combo box items text by :

```
my_combo.Items [i_index] = "some string";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do that is in this way:

```
ui->myComboBox->setItemText(index,"your text");
```

Comment: Where did you get that?, any reference? cause i do not find the setItemText method

Comment: Hi, you can find that method in the **QComboBox** class documentation: [link] (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#setItemText)